# 5V Pin and i2c (GPIO Expander MCP23017) acting VERY strange

Tags: i2c

This is the case,
I've got an MCP23017 IC to expand the outputs on the Raspberry Pi 2 as the others are going to be used (A0 A1 and A2 connected to 0V and RESET pin connected to 5V). 
Here are the problems:

When I first tested my IC today, it didn't work anymore, but 30 seconds later when I tried again, it worked correctly. This was strange and I saw that only 3.8V was delivered in total to the IC, which should be 5V. And while it was still working, 2minutes later, it changed again to 5V.

From a specific moment, everything stopped working, I tried 2 other MCP23017 ICs which also didn't work. It wouldn't show up the expander when doing:

```
i2cdetect -y 1
```

Almost an hour later, after testing everything in parts, nothing changed actually, tested it and didn't work again, then I tried again and it strangely enough worked again (again it only gave 3.8V!), one thing I noticed now is that the IC became hot so I shut down the RPi 2 correctly and turned the power of.

Other notes: when it didn't work, it also sometimes gave 3.8V and sometimes gave 5V, and the IC also became hot. And when it did work, it's exactly the same story.

This is a picture of the situation, (might the wood be giving the problem?? idk):

[image]

I hope you can help me out, as I really don't want to be struggling with this. Any hints/tips/possible explanations are very welcome!

Comment: Btw, by "the IC is getting hot", i mean really hot, it shouldn't be that way.

Comment: If it gets hot you have wired it incorrectly.  That probably accounts for the voltage changes as well.  Not much we can do to help unless you declutter your breadboard to give a clear view of the connections between the Pi and the chip.

Comment: @joan http://i64.tinypic.com/316nr42.jpg

The SCL and SDA pins are connected to the correct pins on the raspberry pi2b+, and the black (+) is connected to pin 2 on the RPi2, the grey (-) is connected to the ground at pin 39

Comment: I'd remove all but the minimum number of wires.  If it gets hot it is wired wrong.  Here is a pretty minimal set-up.  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=954792#p954792.  The resistors are SDA/SCL pull-ups to 3V3 (I2C bus 0 doesn't have pull-ups).

Comment: the pull-ups are internal on the RPi 2 i have right? and the outputs needs to be 5V, the MCP23017 accepts 1.7 - 5.5 V, i guess it sends to the output what i give it right? or not?

Comment: Bus 0 doesn't have pull-ups, bus 1, which you are using does.  Powering from 5V is fine.  Strictly speaking it may not work with the Pi when powered from 5V (logic high input is 0.8 * Vcc, or 4V, more than a Pi's GPIO at 3V3).  The output is open collector so it won't be 5V.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/download/file.php?id=14378 why are there resistors going from the SCL and SDA going to the +3.3V in that photo?

Comment: Well 3.3V works very fine but ofcourse the output LEDS doesn't work very optimally, do you think that the 5V as VDD was the source of all this problems?

Comment: No, I have powered the chip from 5V and used it on the Pi, as have many others.  While it is technically out of spec. it seems to work.  If all you have changed is power to 3V3 rather than 5V I'd be concerned that the underlying problem is still there.

Comment: But the IC is totally not hot and working very correctly now.. hmm

Comment: I can't explain that.

Comment: It's strange, because actually if i i2cdetect -y 1 on 3.3V, it finds it, and 2seconds later if i try the same thing at 5V it doesnt find it anymore, and when switching back, it finds it again, so that must be the reason? btw i have level switchers (3.3V to 5V signals) for raspberry pi, so if i level up the signal on the SDA and SCL to 5V, and input 5V, it would also have to work isn't it?

Comment: well it started becoming hot again, now on 3.3v, one thing i notice now is that it's starting to get hot from the first moment i place my voltmeter. Could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: still it only works with 3.3v

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue with this chip, despite wiring it correctly.

The issue appears to be that when one of the banks is set as an *input* and connected to a high source (i.e., 5v), about 20mv can sink into the chip. Not much individually, but considering you can have 16 inputs, it can heat up pretty fast.

This is resolved by enabling the pull-up resistors on the inputs. The process for doing so is simple: send the register bit to identify the appropriate register (0x16, 0x0C, 0x06, or 0x0D depending on the mode and bank you are using) and set it to 0xFF. Detailed instructions below, and lots of other useful details on the datasheet.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296536/are-pull-up-resistors-needed-when-connecting-buttons-to-a-io-expander

Comment: Thank you for answering, but the pins were only used as output (lighting up LEDs), so I'm not sure if this would help. I solved it back then by connecting the source to 3.3V instead of 5V, the LEDs still light up but not as much as it should, which is too bad. Should have said this in the original question probably